# why am I getting a MySQl error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error when I run the below code. I dont know why I am getting this error. I echoed the query to make sure that the syntax is correct I checked the query in a syntax checker to make sure that the query contains no syntax errors. and even tested in PHP my admin.

The query that is producing this error is the query that is in the for loop with numberofcolor and numberofsizes

Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

```
<?php include('includes/db.php'); include('../functions/functions.php');?>
<?php require './p_struct/head.php';?>
<?php require './p_struct/header.php';?>


<?php require './p_struct/sidenav.php';?>
<div class="main" style="font-size: 20px">

    <form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="chells">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_title" required="required"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>category</td>
                <td><select name="product_category" >
                <option>Select a Category</option>

                <?php

                     $get_cats = " select * from categories"; 
                     $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

                     while($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats))
                     {
                            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
                            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_data']; 


                        echo "

                        <option vallue = '$cat_id' >$cat_title </option>

                        ";
                        }
                ?>


                </select></td>

            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>featured</td>
                <td><select name="product_featured" >
                <option>featured</option>
                <option>not featured</option>
                </select></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>price</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_price" required="required"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>image</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="product_image" required="required"></td>

            </tr>

                        <tr>
                <td>big image</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="product_big_image" required="required"></td>

            </tr>

                          <tr>
                <td>cart image</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="product_cart_image" required="required"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>keywords</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" required="required"></td>

            </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td> Colors</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                             <?php

                                $get_colors = "SELECT * FROM `product_colors`";
                                $run_get_colors = mysqli_query($con, $get_colors);

                                while($row_get_color = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_colors))
                                {
                                    $colorS = $row_get_color['color'];
                                    echo '<label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name = "mycolor[]" value="'.$colorS.'" >'.$colorS.'</label>';  
                                }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>

                             <tr>
                        <td> Sizes</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                             <?php

                                $get_sizes = "SELECT * FROM `product_sizes`";
                                $run_get_sizes = mysqli_query($con, $get_sizes);

                                while($row_get_sizes = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_sizes))
                                {
                                    $sizesS = $row_get_sizes['size'];
                                    echo '<label class="checkbox-inline" ><input type="checkbox" name = "mysizes[]" value="'.$sizesS.'" >'.$sizesS.'</label>';  

                                }
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>description</td>
                <td><textarea name="product_description" cols="20" rows="5" ></textarea></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Product" name="insert_post"></td>
            </tr>

    </table>
</form>


</body>

</html>

<?php 
    global $con;

        if( isset($_POST['insert_post']))
        {
                        $a = rand(100, 999);
                        $b = rand(100, 999);
            $product_id = $a.$b;    

            $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
            $product_category = $_POST['product_category'];
            $product_featured = $_POST['product_featured'];
            $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
            $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
            $product_description = $_POST['product_description'];
                        $color_array = $_POST['mycolor'];
                        $sizes_array = $_POST['mysizes'];
            $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
                        $product_big_image = $_FILES['product_big_image']['name'];
                        $product_cart_image = $_FILES['product_cart_image']['name'];
            $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
                        $product_big_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_big_image']['tmp_name'];
                        $product_cart_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_cart_image']['tmp_name'];

            move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");
                        move_uploaded_file($product__big_image_tmp,"product_big_images/$product_big_image");
                        move_uploaded_file($product_cart__image_tmp,"product_cart_images/$product_cart_image");

         $insert_product = " insert into products (product_id,product_cat, product_featured, product_title, product_price, product_desc,product_image,product_big_image,product_cart_image,product_keywords) values ($product_id,'$product_category','$product_featured','$product_title','$product_price','$product_description','$product_image','$product_big_image','$product_cart_image','$product_keywords')";

        $run_insert_query = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

                $number_of_colors = count($color_array);

                for($i=0; $i <$number_of_colors; $i++)
                {
                    $curr_color_value = $color_array[$i];
                    $add_color_att = "INSERT INTO `attributes`( `id`, `att_type`, `att_value`) VALUES ($product_id, 'color','$curr_color_value');";
                    $run_add_color_att = mysqli_query($con, $add_color_att);

                    /*       if($run_add_color_att)
                    {
                       echo "COLOR ADDED!";
                    }

                     else {
                           echo "COLOR NOT ADDED!";
                     }*/

                }

                $number_of_sizes = count($sizes_array);
                for($s=0; $s <$number_of_sizes; $s++)
                {
                    $curr_size_value = $number_of_sizes[$s];
                    $add_size_att = "INSERT INTO `attributes`( `id`, `att_type`, `att_value`) VALUES ($product_id, `size`,`$curr_size_value`)";
                    $run_add_size_att = mysqli_query($con, $add_size_att);

                    /*        if($run_add_size_att)
                    {
                       echo "SIZE ADDED!";
                    }

                     else {
                           echo "SIZE NOT ADDED!";
                     }*/
                }

                if($run_insert_query)
                {
                   echo "PRODUCT ADDED!";
                }

                 else {
                       echo "PRODUCT NOT ADDED!";
                 }




    } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: @MouradKaroudi the syntax in the query is wrong? please point out the syntax error

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to let on the error message you got? There's no point in letting people guess.

Comment: And obligatory link: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: @mario updated I had forgetten thank you for pointing it out

Comment: their is too many  wrong syntax in your code like why you using `global $db` and your code not written in function. you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

```
$add_size_att = "INSERT INTO `attributes`( `id`, `att_type`, `att_value`) VALUES ($product_id, `size`,`$curr_size_value`)";
```

your using the incorrect quote type here the ` should be ' around the string values:

```
 $add_size_att = "INSERT INTO `attributes`( `id`, `att_type`, `att_value`) VALUES ($product_id, 'size','$curr_size_value')";
```

also should size be `$size`?

Comment: thanks I placed the quotes but still have an issue..size should not be $size

Comment: @OshaneBaker you have multiple sql queries, this one was certainly wrong, it does not mean another was not also. which one(s) is returning an error?